# Does p2 have the ability to verify file's checksum ？

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, equinox, p2

I have an Eclipse RCP application with p2. If someone modifies one of my plug-ins, can my applciation use p2 to verify the file's checksum（e.g. md5）and download the correct plug-in from remote p2 repository to replace it ?

Comment: Yes, Equinox can [_"checking signatures at bundle install-time, or bundle load-time"_](https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/security/). First is done for signed plugins/bundles by default, second not by default for performance reasons.

Comment: If an incorrect plug-in is found, can p2 download the correct one to replace it ? Or I have to achieve this function by myself?

Comment: I would guess, without knowing it, that you have to write some glue code for that case that triggers [Eclipse Equinox](https://github.com/eclipse-equinox/) to download and install the correct plugins/bundles. Hopefully someone else will answer this.